# How to insert some processed data into another table automatically by ruby on rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database

example:

I have a Deposit Table => `deposit = $100`, `date_added = Time.now`, `profit_percent = 0.01`. `user_id`

The process => `profit = deposit * profit_percent`, `date = Time.now`

earning_history Table => `profit` , `date`, `user_id`

I want to do the process each month automatically and insert into earning history for all members. a month is based on `date_added.1.month` so it's differ for any member. The rake is not for infrequently jobs. Corn jobs maybe okay but how can I use it for all members with different date and time!

Can anyone help me, please guide me in details... any plugin suggestion, any workflow?

---

Edited:

Look I have an `accounts` table > Member chooses an `account`

I have a `deposits` table > Member deposits an `amount`

I have a `profits` table > it seeks in `deposits` and grab the `amount` and `date_added`, process it and add the `profit` and `date` (`Time.now`) to `profits` table

how can I say the server to do this automatically for `profits` table, to grab `amount`, process it and add it to `profits` table for all members! I know SQL code also ruby's, I just don't know how to communicate with server to do this! **Model**, **Controller**?!

As I know in **MVC**, **browser** sends command `controller` and `controller` connect `model` and `model` connect to `database` then it returns to `controller` then `view` then **browser**.

I want only **model and database** do this for my application, not browser command. :-s

Answer (score 0):

"whenever"(https://github.com/javan/whenever) gem should solve your issue.  Take a look at this Rails cast by Ryan Bates again: http://railscasts.com/episodes/164-cron-in-ruby

Answer (score -1):

Use https://github.com/javan/whenever

#### whenever schedule.rb

```
set :output, "somewhere/logs/cron.log"

#This will be executed everyday after midnight.

every :day, :at => '0:1am' do
  rake "process_monthly_earning"
end
```

#### process_monthly_earning.rake

```
implement your logic here
```

#### Or you can implement a `after_save` hook in Deposit model.

```
after_save :process_monthly_earning

private:

def process_monthly_earning
  if new_record?  #use it if then earnings are editable
    #check if any monthly earnings are there, if any then update else create
  else
    #adjust the earning
  end 
end
```

Comment: if you need to calculate the profit in a specific interval then a cron job is enough. You dont need a separate model to calculate the profit. a rake task will be good choice which will be executed as cron job